# Amplifier Classes

Tags: transistors, amplifier

I am trying to learn more about the different types of amplifiers and got confused. I understand that there are 2 amplifiers: Voltage amplifier and a power amplifier. Do power amplifiers or voltage amplifiers or both amplifiers have class A, B, AB, and C. And is common emitter, common base, and common collector different ways to set up these amplifiers?

Comment: The term "power amplifier" is misleading. Power cannot be amplified. In fact, a so-called "power amplifier" is intended only to PROVIDE some power to the load.

Comment: @LvW Of course an amplifier can amplify power. Power gain, (signal power out)/(signal power in), is often a useful measure of what an amplifier is doing.

Comment: @ John Doty Yes - I agree. My wording was not exaxt enough. It was my intention to say that the main purpose of a so-called "power amp" is not amplification but to provide power to the load.

Comment: @LvW Not necessarily. Often, a low noise front end amplifier needs power gain to overcome the noise of subsequent stages.

Comment: Better to think of  voltage amplifiers as different to current amplifiers, and to think of power amplifiers as different to small-signal amplifiers.  Generally a small-signal amplifier stage is used to amplify voltages, and a power amplifier stage is used to amplify current. A complete power amplifier usually involves multiple stages... first amplifying the voltage, leading to one or more stages that amplify current.

Comment: @LvW Pretty much every amplifier amplifies power by reverting to an external power source. You don't call a mere transformer an "amplifier". Your objection would appear to apply to the term "amplifier" in general rather than just to "power amplifier".

Comment: @user107063 Yes, agreed. The term "amplifier" in general must not be misunderstood.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume you have a microphone, and you want to hear the sound in your room. Your friend recommended a 10" 8-Ohm speaker. You then later found out that the speaker requires 1 W of power to produce considerable amount of sound so that everyone can hear. This means that the voltage needs to be amplified to ~3 Vrms to drive the load.

The voltage coming from the source, 1 to 10 mV, is too low. Can't drive the load directly.

So, just build a BJT amplifier with 300 V/V gain then. Easy!

You start your research, and learn that one of the easiest ways to have high voltage gains is to use a BJT amplifier called **"class A"** as it can bring significant amount of voltage gain, and with only two resistors! And multiple of them can be cascaded to have even higher gains! Brilliant!

Build a multi-stage BJT amplifier to have 300 V/V gain. Apply the input, check the output from the scope. You see 3 Vrms on the scope! Perfect! This should be enough to drive the load!

Connect the speaker to your amplifier. Apply the input! Oh no. No sound at all! Why? Disconnect the load, check with the scope again. Works normal. Put the load back. No output!

Because all the power delivered by your amplifier is dissipated by the output impedance, which is the collector resistance! The output impedance which is probably a few kiloohms "stole" all the voltage, so the 8-Ohm load got nothing at all. But how could you see the output on the scope? Well, because the scope shows an impedance of megaohms which is way higher than the amp's output impedance. So it could take the output voltage with almost no loss.

Okay then. Decrease the collector resistance to decrease the output impedance. Easy!

Oops. Too much power dissipated. 10+ Watts of consumption to deliver 1 W? Horrible, isn't it? Tweak a little to find a sweet spot? Nah. Too much hassle.

---

Okay. Let's find another amplifier that has a low output impedance.

Found one! It's called **"Class B"**. Two transistors only. Simple! But... It doesn't bring any voltage gain. It also distorts the output. Requires biasing to eliminate distortion, then gets a name of **"Class AB"**. But still, no voltage gain.

But why does it even exist? What's the point of having something with no voltage gain! And it's called "amplifier" O_o What does it amplify, actually?

Well, it gets a voltage from a source as input, and outputs the same (amplitude) voltage, but it can drive low-impedance loads! So, if I apply 3 V from a source with relatively high output impedance, I'll still get 3 V at the output but I can drive an 8-ohm load. Sounds good.

---

Now if you combine your BJT amplifier with a class-AB amplifier, you should be able to drive your speaker.

---

---

> I understand that there are 2 amplifiers: Voltage amplifier and a power amplifier.

Theoretically, all the amplifier classes are "power" amplifiers. You apply a few microwatts or nanowatts, and you get a few tens/hundreds milliwatts or even higher.

Take the multi-stage class-A amplifier above, for example. The input is 10 mV, the input impedance can be about 10 kiloohms. Making a total input power of 10 nW. And you got 3 Vrms. If you apply this voltage across a 10 kiloohm resistor, you'll get 0.9 mW, which means a power gain of 90,000!

But how useful is it? Can it drive your speaker? No. But it can generate enough voltage. So it can be used as a "voltage amplifier".

Now take the Class-B or Class-AB amplifier. Again, it's a power amplifier. Assume an input impedance of 10 kiloohms. Voltage input is 3 Vrms, making an input power of 0.9 mW. And outputs 3 Vrms across an 8-ohm load without any problems, making a power gain of 1000+!

Same question: How useful is it? Can it amplify the signal coming from your microphone? No. It requires an already high voltage input. But it outputs enough current. So it can be used as a "current amplifier".

Combine a voltage amplifier and a current amplifier, and you get a true power amplifier.

> And is common emitter, common base, and common collector different ways to set up these amplifiers?

Each configuration is for different purposes, and each have their own advantages and disadvantages

- Use class-A (a.k.a. common emitter) for high input impedance and high voltage gains (combine two of them to make a differential amplifier, when needed). Works as a "pre-amplifier" to generate enough voltage for the following stages. The output impedance will be relatively high, so more suitable for stages having high input impedances. Can also be used with an impedance matching network (e.g. transformer).
- Use class-B or class-AB (a.k.a. buffer or follower) for high output currents. Can be combined with class-A for driving low-impedance loads. Doesn't bring any voltage gain, but provides good amount of current gain.

Comment: Great story! This is how it should be explained to people, in a human way, with a lot of emotions and enthusiasm... and not as in classical textbooks, formally and soullessly...

Comment: So are class A power amps (like vacuum tube designs) using an output transformer to lower their output impedance to drive loudspeakers? Or are amps that say they are class A not really class A?

Comment: @ToddWilcox `So are class A power amps (like vacuum tube designs) using an output transformer to lower their output impedance to drive loudspeakers?` yes. A single-ended class-A power amp with 6L6 has about 6k output impedance. So an impedance-matching transformer with ~6k-to-8 (or with tapped secondaries for different impedances) is used.

Comment: As colorful as this answer is,  it is unfortunately incorrect.   Class A and B has nothing to do with whether it is a voltage gain or voltage buffer stage.   You can have class B voltage gain stages and Class A output stages (as well as common emitter versions of both).  A and B just indicate how much of the wave cycle the active device is turned on,  A is all the time,  B is half the time.   AB is just a little more than half the time.

Comment: @ToddWilcox vacuum tube have really high output impedance because they really can't deliver much current.   You can find class A transistor amps which don't need output transformers because they can be designed with low output impedance,  despite what this answer says.   They usually have huge heat sinks though because class A amps have the transistors always active and burning up power (which is what it means to be class A)

Comment: @JoelKeene `... it is unfortunately incorrect` I can't see what parts are incorrect in my answer. `Class A and B has nothing to do with whether it is a voltage gain or voltage buffer stage.` I didn't say the opposite. I wanted the answer to be as non-technical as possible to make it "readable" hence I didn't mention all "impractical" possibilities. `You can find class A transistor amps which don't need output transformers because they can be designed with low output impedance, despite what this answer says.` I didn't say that. I already mentioned class A with low Zo and how lossy it could be.

Comment: @JoelKeene I'm not sure if you have really read or understood the answer. My primary language is not English, which may have caused some misunderstandings, but anywhere in the answer I didn't say or mean any of the things you mentioned.

Comment: @ToddWilcox one thing to note: 6L6's output impedance is normally different for different configs. ~6k output impedance is for class-A in triode operation, nor for all of them.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I will go to chat for more details but basically the problem is that everything you have said about class B amplifiers could also be true of class A amplifiers,  and the other way around,  as you have described characteristics that have nothing to do with amplifier class.   You have done a good job of describing power vs voltage gain stages,  but class A, B, or C is only dependent on the active time of the device.   Unfortunately you cannot answer a technical question in a less technical way than that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150481/discussion-between-joel-keene-and-rohat-kilic).

Answer (score 5):

A simple explanation of "power amps" and "voltage amps". Let's cut to the chase.

"Voltage amps" do exactly what the name suggests - take a smaller voltage and make it larger. However, they may not be able to supply much *current*. A typical scenario is (for example) a signal of 100mV peak which is amplified by 20, now we have 2V peak. However, we may not be able to supply much *current* at the output. Let's say 5mA is the max. The lowest load we can drive with this is 2/5 kilohms or 400 ohms. Probably we would choose by design to not go so near to the max, and arrange that the next stage has an input impedance of at least 1k, maybe a lot more. Output power into that load is V^2/R - not going to calculate in detail, but with V in the volts range and R at say 1000, the power is pretty small - in the mW range. (*)

A typical device to do this would be a part of a dual or quad opamp, quite a small device. It isn't dissipating much heat, it doesn't need to be physically big.

Now let's say that we have the same scenario, but the load is an 8R loudspeaker. Suddenly we need to supply a peak output current of 2/8A = 250mA. This is a very different beast! To supply that kind of current something physically bigger is generally needed, and there will probably be some way of getting the heat out of the output stage.

Ah yes, the output stage. This is where we start talking about class A, B, C, D. In essence there is a trade off between giving a faithful reproduction of the input and efficiency. In order, we can roughly say this:

Class A reproduces very faithfully but is very inefficient.
Class B is more efficient but starts to have some noticeable distortion (if we are talking about audio).
Class AB is a compromise between A and B - much lower distortion than B but much more efficient than A.
Class C is very distorted but getting more efficient.
CLass D is ... different. It's basically a controlled switch mode supply which gives great efficiency, low distortion (but typically introduces a lot of HF artefacts out of the audio band - you can't hear them but they are there.

(*) OPK, the math : 2V peak is 2*0.71V rms = 1.42V. V^2 is therefore 2V. So we get 2mW into 1k and 250mW into 8R - a factor of more than 100 difference.

**Summary** : A voltage amp has voltage gain, that is all. A power amp is an amp (which may or may not have voltage gain) which can drive a low impedance load - it has a beefy output stage which is either class A/AB/B/C/D which affects efficiency and distortion a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There are also current amplifiers, charge amplifiers, transconductance amplifiers, transimpedance amplifiers, ... Something comes in, something else comes out.

What's common is a topological choice that influences what an individual amplifying element can do. Class is about how much of the dynamic range of the input an individual amplifying element handles.

Most amplifiers use multiple amplifying elements.

Comment: So is a class a or ab a class for a voltage amplifier and a power amplifier?

Comment: @MarcusMarchese The class has nothing to do with whether it amplifies voltage, power, or something else.

Comment: What makes a power amplifier different from a voltage amplifier if they are both class a?

Comment: @Marcus Marchese, They are not different; they are the same biased 1-transistor amplifier stage. Some difference may be taking the output signal through a step-down transformer in the powerful class A amplifier stage.

Comment: @MarcusMarchese A power amplifier delivers more power on its output than it receives on its input. A voltage amplifier delivers more voltage on its output than it receives on its input. An amplifier might amplify both. And some things we call "amplifiers"  amplify neither.

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that there are 2 amplifiers: Voltage amplifier and a power amplifier.

Yes and no. Sort of. It's not really a distinction that helps you design or understand amplifiers. I can understand though why an elementary course on electronics might make such a claim.

All amplifiers have to be designed to drive the load they're intended to drive, and output the power that they need to.

A useful distinction could be made with whether the efficiency of the amplifier output is important, when it's driving its intended load.

If the load is a high resistance like a meter or another amplifier input drawing very little current, then we can afford to use a low efficiency output stage, like a class A for instance. Then we might call this a voltage amplifier. If you look at almost any op-amp internal schematic, they frequently use class AB or B outputs, to reduce their internal dissipation when outputting a reasonable current (in mA to the tens of mA range). I think most engineers would still call these voltage amplifiers.

If the load requires considerable power, then the low efficiency of class A might be problematic, so audio 'power amplifiers' will typically use class B or AB (or these days class D). A class A amplifier would generate large amounts of heat driving a reasonable level to loud speakers. This doesn't stop a handful of motivated audiophools using a class A space heater to drive their speakers.

Perhaps a way to sum it up would be that in a 'power amplifier', the output current is an important part of the specification. For a 'voltage amplifier', it's an incidental part. Returning to the op-amp example, it doesn't really matter whether the output will source 5 mA or 20 mA, both will drive most feedback resistors and meter loads.

Answer (score 3):

The differences between voltage and power amplifiers has been pretty well covered already so I'll focus on amplifier classes.

Classes A through C are based on conduction angle. Imagine a \$2~V_{pk-pk}\$ sine wave, the voltage will be:

- \$~~~0\$ V @ \$0^{\circ}\$
- \$+1\$ V @ \$90^{\circ}\$
- \$~~~0\$ V @ \$180^{\circ}\$
- \$-1\$ V @ \$270^{\circ}\$
- \$~~~0\$ V @ \$360^{\circ}\$
  [image: Sine Wave]

In a Class A amplifier the active device (transistor, tube, etc.) will be biased to conduct for the entire \$360^{\circ}\$.

In a Class B amplifier it will be biased to conduct for \$180^{\circ}\$.

In Class C it will conduct for something less than \$180^{\circ}\$.

And in Class AB it will conduct for something between \$180^{\circ}\$ and \$360^{\circ}\$.

All of these can be done using a single active device, Class B and AB don't necessarily indicate a push-pull arrangement as some have suggested, it's just that they are usually used that way.

Class A is used when you want to minimize distortion. Since there's no point where the active device is in cut-off it avoids the most non-linear portion of the device's characteristic curves. Since it conducts all the time whether there's a signal or not it wastes power.

Class B is used when you want to reduce power dissipation in the active devices and improve efficiency. It is generally used with two devices in a push-pull or complementary symmetry arrangement so that one device amplifies from \$0^{\circ}\$ to \$180^{\circ}\$ and the second device amplifies from \$180^{\circ}\$ to \$360^{\circ}\$. This way neither device is conducting when there is no signal, increasing efficiency. The trade off is that when conduction switches from one device to the other they go through their non-linear region creating what's called cross-over distortion.

Class AB is a trade-off between A and B. The active devices are biased slightly into conduction reducing the cross-over distortion seen in Class B while not conducting as much with no signal as a Class A would, increasing efficiency.

Class C is used in RF amplifiers, the active device only conducts for a small part of the waveform and depends on the flywheel effect of resonant circuits to fill in the missing part of the waveform.

Technically you could use any of these classes with any transistor circuit topology, CE, CB or CC, but some combinations are more useful than others.

Comment: Good point... But I wonder how it will explain the operation of these circuits if they are DC amplifiers?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I can’t say I’ve ever seen anyone talk about classes for DC amplifiers. It’s not like I made this up, this is how the classes are defined.

Answer (score 1):

## Looking for a meaningful classification

### Power amplifiers

Classifying power amplifier types with meaningless capital letters is pointless. Probably someone did it at the time because they did not bother to come up with meaningful names, and since then it has been handed down through the centuries. Here is an example of a more meaningful classification of power amplifiers:

Class A  - biased power amplifier

Class B  - unbiased push-pull stage

Class AB - biased push-pull stage

Class C  - pulse power amplifier

Class D  - switching power amplifier

### Voltage amplifiers

The "common-something" classification makes a bit more sense, but it is also not what it should be. You should focus rather on what the individual configurations are than how they are labeled. Here is an example of a more meaningful classification of voltage (pre)amplifiers:

Common-emitter amplifier stage - base-controlled amplifier stage

Common-base amplifier stage - emitter-controlled amplifier stage

Common-collector amplifier stage - emitter follower

Comment: You can add on class E: resonant switching power amplifier. Not sure I agree with your depiction of class C as a pulse amplifier, though; it's just a highly nonlinear, but not quite switching, amplifier.

Comment: @Hearth, I dare not add Class E amplifiers because I am not very familiar with it; looks more like an externally excited oscillator to me.  In fact, I don't like the subject of amplifier classes, as well as any other kind of classification; I am more attracted to the ideas on which they are built.